# How to display a picture in a picture box when row header mouse click event is used in a datagrid view?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a data grid view and a picture box. I need to use the row header mouse click event and load a picture from data grid to the picture box.

```
private void dataGridView1_RowHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Column2"].Value.ToString();
            textBox2.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Column8"].Value.ToString();
            textBox3.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Column4"].Value.ToString();
            textBox4.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Column6"].Value.ToString();
            textBox5.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Column5"].Value.ToString();
            textBox6.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Column9"].Value.ToString();
            // pictureBox1.Image = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Column3"].Value.ToString();

}
```

I have tried,

```
        /* byte[] nm = new byte[0];
         object x = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Column3"];
         nm = (byte[])x;

         MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(nm);
         pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);*/

        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream((byte[])dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["Column3"].Value);
        pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);
```

Any kind help would be highly appreciated.Thank you!.

Comment: What the Column3 contains: url, path, byte array?

Comment: column 3 contains a byte array

Comment: And what? You get an exception? Your code should work.

Comment: i get an invalid cast exception, near nm = (byte[])x;

Comment: So, there is not a byte array. Show the code how you put the data in this column `DataGridView`.

Comment: private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {   
            byte[] imageBt = null;
                FileStream fs = new FileStream(picLoc, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
                imageBt = br.ReadBytes((int)fs.Length);

Comment: string type=comboBox1.GetItemText(comboBox1.SelectedItem);
                SqlCommand newCmd = conn.CreateCommand();
                newCmd.Connection = conn;
                newCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                newCmd.CommandText = "insert into Tb(picture) values('" + imageBt + "')"; newCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();conn.Close(); FillGrid();

Comment: public void FillGrid()
        {
            DataSet ds = dba.getAllMembers();
            dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables["Tb"].DefaultView;
        }

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
   Image.GetThumbnailImageAbort myImage = new Image.GetThumbnailImageAbort(ThumbnailCallback);
   Image image1 = ((Image)dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["Column3"].Value).GetThumbnailImage(200, 200, myImage, IntPtr.Zero);
   this.pictureBox1.Image = image1;
```

Comment: Thank you OzgeTas,

Comment: but i get an error as 'ThumbnailCallback' does not exist in the current context.

Comment: i have used system.drawing namespace and i have saved the image in data base as an array of bytes.

Comment: You should add this : public bool ThumbnailCallback()
{
    return false;
}

Comment: You can find detail in msdn. [https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.getthumbnailimage(v=vs.110).aspx]

Comment: I'm sorry to say that it does not work either with true or false.It gives an invalid cast exception error near (200,200,myImage,IntPtr.Zero);